# How and when to initialise configuration in Python?

Tags: python

I'm getting pretty confused as to how and where to initialise application configuration in Python 3.

I have configuration that consists of application specific config (db connection strings, url endpoints etc.) and logging configuration.

Before my application performs its intended function I want to initialise the application and logging config.

After a few different attempts, I eventually ended up with something like the code below in my main entry module. It has the nice effect of all imports being grouped at the top of the file (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports), but it doesn't feel right since the config modules are being imported for side effects alone which is pretty non-intuitive.

```
import config.app_config # sets up the app config
import config.logging_config # sets up the logging config

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

`config.app_config` looks something like follows:

```
_config = {
    'DB_URL': None
}


_config['DB_URL'] = _get_db_url()

def db_url():
    return _config['DB_URL']

def _get_db_url():
    #somehow get the db url
```

and `config.logging_config` looks like:

```
if not os.path.isdir('.\logs'):
        os.makedirs('.\logs')

    if os.path.exists('logging_config.json'):
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            config = json.load(f)
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=log_level)
```

What is the common way to set up application configuration in Python? Bearing in mind that I will have multiple applications each using the `config.app_config` and `config.logging_config` module, but with different connection string possibly read from a file

Comment: Is it Django? Just want to make sure

Comment: No, not using Django, but I did end up copying their approach since its really elegant (https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/__init__.py). Only thing I don't like is the use of environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a cut down version of the Django approach: [https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/**init**.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/__init__.py)

It seems pretty elegant and has the nice benefit of working regardless of which module imports settings first.